# Easiest way to validate object against config file

Tags: c#, .net, json, automapper

I am running an nancyfx-based restful service and need to communicate to an cobol based machine.

I'm getting requests in the form of json and bind it into an object. My configfile is a json-file as well in which i am setting the bound (left or right), the amount of numbers after a decimal point and the overall length of the field.

I want to validate each field and will later need to output each field in a given format as the cobol program needs it's values (eg. negative values like "-123,45" need to be in the schema of "12345-").

These are some of my properties that i've generated off my json config file:

```
    public class Companyid
    {
        public string bound { get; set; }
        public int decimals { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customerid
    {
        public string bound { get; set; }
        public int decimals { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
    }

    public class Zip
    {
        public string bound { get; set; }
        public int decimals { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Companyid companyid { get; set; }
        public Customerid customerid { get; set; }
        public Zip zip { get; set; }
    }
```

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "companyid": {
        "bound": "right",
        "decimals": 0,
        "length": 2,
        "pos": 1
    },
    "customerid": {
        "bound": "right",
        "decimals": 0,
        "length": 6,
        "pos": 2
    },
    "zip": {
        "bound": "right",
        "decimals": 0,
        "length": 5,
        "pos": 13
    }
}
```

My customer-object (the user-input) looks like this:

```
     public class Customer
        {
            public string companyid { get; set; }
            public int customerstatus { get; set; }
            public string customersince { get; set; }
            public string customerid { get; set; }
        }
```

Finally, i'll also need to make it possible to put these items in the correct order (so change the order from companyid | customerid | zip **to** zip | companyid | customerid)

EDIT for clarity:

Is there an easy way to go through all properties of my object and receive the property value?

How could I improve my object to make iteration possible/easier? Might Automapper be a valid solution to my problem? And if so, how would I implement it?